# Xcode loads same image for two different strings

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have two images in the assets folder named like so:

```
backgroundImage = @"background.wood";
backgroundImageLight = @"background.wood.lighting";
```

The names in the assets folder are the same as these strings. When I try to load these images, no matter what backgroundLight always loads the background image. I had to change the name in the assets folder and in the string from "background.wood.lighting" to "somedifferentstring" for it to actually load the correct image. Is this a bug with Xcode? Why does it load the same image for these different strings? Does it have to do with the beginnings being similar? I tried emptying the cache manually to make sure that the image wasn't pre loaded but that didn't help either.

UPDATE:

The code to display/load the images:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:backgroundImage];
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
background.size = self.frame.size;
background.zPosition = background_z_order;

SKSpriteNode *backgroundLight = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:backgroundImageLight];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", backgroundImage, backgroundImageLight);
backgroundLight.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
backgroundLight.size = self.frame.size;
backgroundLight.zPosition = background_z_order;

[mainView addChild:background];
[mainView addChild:backgroundLight];
```

UPDATE 2:

All of these load different images, so maybe it's the second "." that throws it off idk:

```
monster.boss.one
monster.fire.redsun
monster.lightning.yellowjaw
monster.normal.greenslither
```

Comment: Pleas post the code you are using to load and display the image.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: @JeffWolski You don't need to see code. Try it yourself; you'll see that this is absolutely true.

Comment: @Minimi (1) Nice one. (2) Don't do that. (3) File a bug report with Apple and see what happens.

Comment: @matt The purpose of seeing the code is to know what the "it" is that you're suggesting I try.

Comment: @JeffWolski I had no difficulty trying it and seeing that what the OP says is true. No code was needed.

Comment: @matt I'm glad to hear that.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last "." is taken to be the start of a file extension. For compatibility with older projects where an asset was moved from the app bundle to the asset catalog when asset catalogs were invented, it is legal to say `@"myImage.jpg"` and this will still be found in the asset catalog if the image set is called `myImage`. The file extension is stripped off and the image set is still found. Similarly, your dot-suffixed `.lightning` is being stripped off and the resulting `background.wood` is found — and that is the end of the search.

So the moral is, Don't Do That. Use an underscore instead of a dot.

Comment: The thing is, if I use a single . it works. for example all fo these load different images:

monster.boss.one
monster.fire.redsun
monster.lightning.yellowjaw
monster.normal.greenslither
...

Comment: You're not thinking about what I said. If you say `a.b.c` we immediately strip off `.c` and try it. If we find `a.b` that is the end of the search. There is no match in the `monster` examples but there is a match in the example you gave in your question.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yea that definitely sounds like that could be the cause, I'll change it to underscores.

Comment: Well here's another thing. I also have a set of images that are called "orb.water, orb.light, orb.fire, etc..." but those don't seem to have this problem either. all those orbs are loaded differently. If what you're saying was true wouldn't it load the first orb texture it finds for each one?

Comment: You're still not listening. We strip off `.water`, but we do not find `orb`. That is not like your test case where strip off `.lightning` and we do find `background.wood`.

Comment: I see, so if it doesn't find the image after assuming the latter part of the string is the extension it goes back and searches for the original string. Interesting implementation choice.

Comment: As I said, this is for backwards compatibility. We still need to search for `myFile.jpg` because `myFile.jpg` might be sitting in the app bundle. But we search for `myFile` first, and we search the asset catalog first.